# Docker cannot port forward to a container, returns socket error 99

Tags: python-2.7, docker, sockets, containers, port

I am trying to run a container from a dockerfile image for a project I am working on. I am able to build the image from the dockerfile, but every time I try making the containers it runs into a consistent socket problem.

**System Info**

OS: Windows 10 Home Edition, v 2004 build 19041

Docker: 2.4.0.0

Python: 2.7

Docker Toolbox: 19.0.3.1

Git: 2.28.0

VirtualBox: 6.0.24

**What I Expect to Happen**

The container to be built and run after inputting the commands.

**What Happens Instead**

The container is created but cannot run and returns a socket error.

**What I am doing**

After navigating to the directory, I perform the following. Powershell is being run in admin mode. After trying to do the same for Docker, I've run into problems where it can only run if I let it start up when I sign in. I'm not sure if I can run it as an admin.

`docker build . -t image_name`

After confirming that the image is built, I try

`docker run --publish 8000:8888 --detach --name container_name image_name`

At this point the container is built but cannot run, and returns the following the logs.

```
Missing privilege separation directory: /var/run/sshd

[I 14:53:32.778 NotebookApp] Writing notebook server cookie secret to /root/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/notebook_cookie_secret

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/usr/local/bin/jupyter-notebook", line 8, in <module>

sys.exit(main())

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jupyter_core/application.py", line 270, in launch_instance

return super(JupyterApp, cls).launch_instance(argv=argv, **kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 663, in launch_instance

app.initialize(argv)

File "<decorator-gen-7>", line 2, in initialize

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 87, in catch_config_error

return method(app, *args, **kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 1630, in initialize

self.init_webapp()

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 1407, in init_webapp

self.http_server.listen(port, self.ip)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/tcpserver.py", line 143, in listen

sockets = bind_sockets(port, address=address)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/netutil.py", line 168, in bind_sockets

sock.bind(sockaddr)

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 228, in meth

return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)

socket.error: [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address

Missing privilege separation directory: /var/run/sshd

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/usr/local/bin/jupyter-notebook", line 8, in <module>

sys.exit(main())

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jupyter_core/application.py", line 270, in launch_instance

return super(JupyterApp, cls).launch_instance(argv=argv, **kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 663, in launch_instance

app.initialize(argv)

File "<decorator-gen-7>", line 2, in initialize

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 87, in catch_config_error

return method(app, *args, **kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 1630, in initialize

self.init_webapp()

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 1407, in init_webapp

self.http_server.listen(port, self.ip)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/tcpserver.py", line 143, in listen

sockets = bind_sockets(port, address=address)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/netutil.py", line 168, in bind_sockets

sock.bind(sockaddr)

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 228, in meth

return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)

socket.error: [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address

Missing privilege separation directory: /var/run/sshd

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/usr/local/bin/jupyter-notebook", line 8, in <module>

sys.exit(main())

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jupyter_core/application.py", line 270, in launch_instance

return super(JupyterApp, cls).launch_instance(argv=argv, **kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 663, in launch_instance

app.initialize(argv)

File "<decorator-gen-7>", line 2, in initialize

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 87, in catch_config_error

return method(app, *args, **kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 1630, in initialize

self.init_webapp()

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 1407, in init_webapp

self.http_server.listen(port, self.ip)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/tcpserver.py", line 143, in listen

sockets = bind_sockets(port, address=address)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/netutil.py", line 168, in bind_sockets

sock.bind(sockaddr)

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 228, in meth

return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)

socket.error: [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address
```

I have confirmed that port 8888 is exposed in the dockerfile, and tried mapping it to 8080 as well with the same results. I have confirmed that ports 8000, 8888, and 8080 are open on my computer, and also tried mapping them to the IP address that I found associated with docker (127.0.0.1). I have also tried to use the `create` and `run` commands in Docker but these do not work either.

[Here is the link to the dockerfile.](https://github.com/deep-scaffold/molecule_generator/tree/master/dockerfile) I have not edited it outside of trying different ports.

Sorry for the wall of text!

Comment: Try running docker as an admin, and also the terminal where you are running those commands

Comment: I know I'm running powershell as an administrator, I'll try Docker now too. I'll update the question based on how it goes.

Comment: So Docker wouldn't run unless I have it start on log in. Once I got that working, I am still running into the same problems. I tested if I could run any other container and I was able to run the getting-started container that docker provides. I tried a few other ports and also ensured that jupyter notebook is on port 8888. At this point I feel that something in the dockerfile is preventing me from having this succeed.

Comment: Can you add your dockerfile....make sure it has a line with `RUN mkdir /var/run/sshd`

Comment: I have attached the link to the dockerfile on Github. I doublechecked and I don't see the command that you have listed. If that is the case, where should I input it?

Comment: You can add that on line 6 and check if it works :)

Comment: Sorry I just saw your comment! I don't know why but Stack Overflow didn't show it. I added the command on line 6 (right at the top of the Dockerfile) and ran through the commands as above, and it is still crashing. I also tried port 80 on my computer as it worked for the getting-started image that docker provides.